# Bug report on babel, biblatex packages (probably latex3 related)

Tags: biblatex, miktex, babel, latex3

I`m using MikTeX (4.8) and after the last update, I'm getting some odd error messages related to  "__text_expand_loop:w has an extra } "
it took me a while to find the possible root of the problem, and it seems related (in my case) to two packages: babel and biblatex

The commands 'generating' the error messages are
\MakeUppercase (if I use the babel package) and
\cite \fullcite (if I use the biblatex package with the abnt style).

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%using the two packages bellow it won't compile
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=abnt,pretty,giveninits,extrayear,repeatfields]{biblatex}

%% if, instead, the babel package isn't loaded and biblatex is used as below, it will work
%%\RequirePackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{modeloTCC.bib}

\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{aâãàá b}


\cite{ABNT:NBR-14724-2011}

\fullcite{ABNT:NBR-14724-2011}

\end{document}
```

FILE modeloTCC.bib

```
@manual{ABNT:NBR-14724-2011,
    title="{NBR}-14724: Informação e Documentação - Trabalhos Acadêmicos - Apresentação",
    author="ABNT",
    organization="ASSOCIAÇÃO BRASILEIRA DE NORMAS TÉCNICAS",
    address="Rio de Janeiro",
    year="2011",
    pages="6"
}
```

the kind of error message I'm getting is:

```
! Argument of \__text_expand_loop:w has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 \MakeUppercase
                   {aâãàá b}
```

and/or

```
! Argument of \__text_expand_loop:w has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.17 \cite{ABNT:NBR-14724-2011}
```

I'm not sure if this is really a babel/biblatex bug, or something related to latex3 or (perhaps) MiKTeX specific.

any help/idea is sure welcome!

Comment: hm curious. You can avoid the error by doing \def\BabelCaseHack{} before loading babel. But I don't know yet, why this is needed in miktex, the versions are the same as in texlive and there it works.

Comment: oh, miktex is missing the newest firstaid package.

Comment: I just tested the \def\BabelCaseHack{} and indeed it works... thanks for the prompt reply!
edit: I mean, I tested it with my original 'project' (which is way bigger than the MWE) and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

miktex missed to update also the firstaid package. This package contains a fix for babel and turns off its redefinition of `\MakeUppercase`.

Until this is corrected in miktex you can turn off the hack by defining a command before loading babel:

```
\def\BabelCaseHack{}

\RequirePackage{babel}
```

Comment: it's odd that, besides babel, it also affected biblatex. as said, just loading biblatex (with abnt style, but not loading babel) resulted in the same kind of error message (with \cite).
thanks again, btw.