# Markdown package in combination with babel produces errors

Tags: errors, miktex, babel, mac, markdown

I have a minimal latex file, using the markdown as well as the babel package:

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{markdown}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\markdownSetup{pipeTables,tableCaptions}
\begin{document}
\markdownInput{./test.md}
\end{document}
```

test.md file:

```markdown
# H1
## H2
Text
```

When I compile it with

```bash
pdflatex --shell-escape document.tex
```

it will give me the following errors:

```
(_markdown_document/e0cf625f64983b2c015d517273d026f8.md.tex
Kapitel 1.
! Argument of \__cmd_expandable_grab_D:NNNwNNn has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.2 \markdownRendererHeadingOne{H1}
                                   \markdownRendererInterblockSeparator
? 
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \__cmd_expandable_grab_D:NNNwNNn was complete.
<to be read again>
```

I've tried compiling it with either `markdown` or `babel` removed, and it will compile fine. Also, it seems the language chosen with babel is irrelevant, it will produce the same exact error.

From my understanding, the file mentioned in the error (`_markdown_document/e0cf625f64983b2c015d517273d026f8.md.tex`) gets produced by the `markdown` package. Its content looks like this:

```tex
\markdownRendererDocumentBegin
\markdownRendererHeadingOne{H1}\markdownRendererInterblockSeparator
{}\markdownRendererHeadingTwo{H2}\markdownRendererInterblockSeparator
{}Text\markdownRendererDocumentEnd
```

Compiling with `lualatex` yields the same errors.

For me, it does not look like there is an 'an extra }', as mentioned in the error.

I am rather stumped, as I cannot for the life of me find out why the error occurs only with the usage of babel. I also can't find any mention of this or a similar error on the internet.

My System:

- MacBook Air 2020 with M1 processor.
- MacOS 13.0.1 Ventura
- MikTex. This is MikTex's report:

```
ReportDate: 2022-11-17 12:24:14
CurrentVersion: 22.1
SetupDate: 2022-07-13 11:58:00
SetupVersion: 22.1
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: 6b3d82b7d / 2022-01-30 11:05:07
OS: Darwin 22.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.1.0: Sun Oct  9 20:14:30 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8792.41.9~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 x86_64
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: /Users/henry/bin
PathOkay: no
LastUpdateCheck: 2022-11-17 09:41:58
LastUpdate: 2022-11-17 09:42:24
LastUpdateDb: 2022-11-17 09:41:58
SystemAdmin: no
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: /Users/henry/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/config
Root1: /Users/henry/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data
Root2: /Users/henry/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install
UserInstall: /Users/henry/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install
UserConfig: /Users/henry/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/config
UserData: /Users/henry/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data
```

If someone has any clue what is happening, I would appreciate any input.

Comment: I couldn't post the full error log, StackExchange would say 'This looks like spam'. [Here](https://pastebin.com/yr94ebxm) is the full log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code fails when executing `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\chaptermark #1->\markboth {\MakeUppercase
```

The problem is that babel redefines it in a way that breaks now. The firstaid package contains a fix, but miktex missed to update it. There is already a bug report, so probably at the next update it should work again.

As work-around you can use latex-dev by compiling with `pdflatex-dev`, or you can disable the redefinition manually:

```
\documentclass{book}
\def\BabelCaseHack{} %work-around
\usepackage{markdown}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\markdownSetup{pipeTables,tableCaptions}
\begin{document}
\markdownInput{./test.md}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This also works for me. Thank you so much. You are a life saver.

Comment: @Henry an alternative is to use `pdflatex-dev`, that has already the correct firstaid.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate how you knew that this bug was the cause of my error? Or have you seen the error before? Thanks!

Comment: I have a rather good crystalball and "miktex" and "babel" was enough to trigger it. (I just saw a similar error the day before: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665414/2388).